# Pricing information for Office Web App Server 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

We want to use Office Web App Server with SharePoint server 2013. we need latest pricing information about Office Web App Server 2013.

I know there is free version of Office Web App Server but it does not support editing the files, so we thinking to install Office Web App Server with edit license. but i did not found anything related license cost.

Answer (score 1):

You need Office licenses volume or otherwise: See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/volume-licensing/2013/05/22/how-to-license-office-web-apps-server/

Answer (score 1):

Office Web Apps 2013 is  a separate product which needs to be installed on a separate server. It can now be used with Exchange Server 2013, Lync 2013 .

For licensing Office Web Apps 2013:-

1. If you ONLY want to have the functionaly to VIEW the documents in your SharePoint ( and not EDIT them), then you do NOT need any license . Just install the product, configure it with SharePoint and you are good to go.
2. If you want to VIEW & EDIT the documents, then you need to have a valid volume license of Office Professional or Office Standard (2010/2013).